# Why is ToString() defined on Object in .NET?

Tags: .net, object, inheritance, tostring

I have always wondered the design choices that lead to the creation of ToString on Object in .NET.

Comment: Probably so that you can call `ToString()` on the elements of a completely heterogeneous collection, without knowing anything at all about the dynamic type of the object you call it on. It also provides a (somewhat) meaningful default implementation that may help you debug or log.

Comment: Are you saying it should be defined somewhere else or that it should not be defined _at all_?

Comment: +1. Pretty clear this question is asking "Why is ToString() defined" and given the documentation has specifics, its not leading to opinion-based answers. Disagree with close votes.

Comment: Retag the question with [java] and you might get closer to the truth.  Are you going to do anything differently when you get the truth?

Comment: @HansPassant Love it - classic "so what" challenge...

Comment: @dStanley Sorry for the ambiguity, I am not challenging the idea of why, I am curious as to the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) gives a pretty clear purpose:

> Object.ToString is the major formatting method in the .NET Framework. It converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for display.

It's defined on `Object` so *all* types have at least a default implementation.  It's `virtual` so types can provide their own implementation if they want to display something other then the class name (without having to know the actual type).  Numeric types override it so their *value* can be displayed by default.

Comment: Real World Practicality baked in from the start.

Comment: What is the advantage of this type of design, instead of having a separate module that accomplishes the same task? Perhaps a static .Parse on String like Int and Double have?

Comment: @SurelyTheresABetterWay You can't override a `static` method, for one, so you couldn't have a custom implementation for custom types.

Comment: @DStanley Is it common to override ToString? I'm still new in professional development, and in 4 years I've never overridden it.

Comment: I wouldn't say "common", but it can be useful. [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx) is a great example of a class that has a very beneficial override.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be at least some way to visually represent a class instance, even if it only shows the class name. For one thing it makes it possible to inspect the values of variables. If we type `?x` in the immediate window, the only way to display the value if `x` is to render it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

According to my edition of "Framework Design Guidelines" .ToString exists to facilitate debugging. On page 272 there is a discussion about best uses for this method and pointing out that "...the debugger uses it as the default way of displaying an object."

Comment: I believe that's a guideline for _overriding_ `ToString`, not the purpose of `ToString` itself.  Although it's a good _practical_ application of `ToString` the purpose goes beyond just debugging.

Comment: What's neat about that book is the discussion and comments included by the authors. Brian Pepin, for example, is quoted as saying "I tend to be very careful with ToString. I treat it as a diagnostic API and seldom use it for presentation to users unless i know exactly how it works..." He goes on to describe a specific instance where it bit him.